# What is the meaning of もう何度目になるだろう？ in this context ? ( MC is remembering about his friends back in an isekai world)

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, video-games

When reading, I don't understand much about 1 sentence especially because "目になる" part, appreciates if someone can explain to me the correct meaning of this sentence o/

Context: MC used to be a Hero in an isekai world, now when he had returned to his original world, he's remembering about his party members while they're traveling together with him back in that isekai world.

> こちらへ戻ってきたときに驚いたことは、時間がほとんど進んでいなかったことだ。
>
> こんなこと誰かに話せば、何を言ってるんだとバカにされるだろう。
>
> でも、俺にとっては間違いなく現実だったし、おそらく一生忘れられない出来事だった。
>
> 【MC】「……ルナ……エマ……レン」
>
> 俺を慕ってくれ、苦楽を共にした彼女たちのことを思い出す。
>
> **もう何度目になるだろう？( my guess : "How many times I've been remembering about this ? " but I'm not sure )**
>
> 【MC】「……また会えるかな」

Comment: This is one thing English cannot say.

Comment: There is another answer I got online , so I will post here for future reference ,helping people to learn JP  : "in particular, 何度目 differs from 何度 in that the first asks for which instance* and the 2nd asks for "how many instances". thats why 何度目 was used. he is asking, present tense, which time this is. as opposed to asking past tense how many it's been. になる can be used with 何度目 because it is a noun referring to a specific instance."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

～め after a counter makes an ordinal number, like 2人目の店員 'the second clerk' or 1本目のビール 'the first beer'. ～度 is a counter and works just as well with it, so 何度目 will be 'what number time' (as awkward as that sounds in English).

I believe ～になる is optional here but it sounds a little better with it. もう何度目だろう and もう何度目になるだろう are basically a difference of 'How many times is it now?' and 'How many times will it be now?'

So yes, you've basically got the right idea.